# Node js MySQL connection Issue

Tags: node.js

I have been trying to establish connection between Node.js application  and mysql and have tried everything and couldn't succeed.

I'm able to connect through PHP application. My port is default where  3306

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });   
[This is the error message I got,I can able to connect through my php application][1]
```

This is the error message I got,I can able to connect through my php application

[image: This is the error message I got,I can able to connect through my php application]

Comment: Did ur application  server has the permission to access the DB??

Comment: Yes,I do have access, In fact am root user

Comment: The error code i get is 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment "bind-address" and assign bind-address="0.0.0.0".
For More Information please refer this,
[Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to connect to DB is to use [pools](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#pooling-connections) to connect to DB.

Copying from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16922985)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
  connection.release();
});
```

This also allow you to make parallel calls to your database.

Comment: I used above code but still not got succeeded .                                var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database: 'promotool'
  });
  
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)
console.log(err);
    connection.release();
  });Got Error   { Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
   F:\projects\upload_promotool\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000 }

Comment: This is weird. Can you try and specify the timeout manually

pool = require('mysql').createPool({
    connectionLimit : 1000,
    connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    aquireTimeout   : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,

Comment: Yeah Its quite wierd stuff,Still got this error code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000 }
F:\projects\upload_promotool\app.js:23
    connection.release();
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined

Comment: Is you got `'release' of undefined`, it means your connection object is undefined. make sure you use the same variables as you have used in the callback function

Comment: pool = require('mysql').createPool({ 
        connectionLimit : 1000, 
        connectTimeout : 60 * 60 * 1000, 
        aquireTimeout : 60 * 60 * 1000, 
        timeout : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database: 'promotool'
 });
  
 pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)
    console.log(err);
    connection.release();
  });